# Error while converting NSData to NSDictionary using NSKeyedUnarchiver

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsdata

I want to `archive` and `Unarchive` data which contains `NSDictionary` object. Crash is observed while `Unarchiving` data. Please find the code and error below,

### Archive:

```
 NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:mydictobject];
```

### Unarchiving:

```
 NSData *Objdata = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 2)   
                    length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 2)];
 NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] 
                                   initForReadingWithData:Objdata];
 NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
                       [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:Objdata]];
[dict objectForKey:@"key1"];
```

### Error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0xfffffff8, 0xffffffc7, 0xf, 0x1, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)'
** First throw call stack:
(0x222b012 0x194e7e 0x222adeb 0xe78c90 0xe7f2 0x3c11 0x19256 0x43f8d5 0x43fb3d 0xe46e83 0x21ea376 0x21e9e06 0x21d1a82 0x21d0f44 0x21d0e1b 0x21857e3 0x2185668 0x39065c 0x2612 0x2545 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Thanks.

Comment: I tried your code without the sqlite part and it worked without problems. You should check that the data read back from sqlite is the same data that you wrote to it.

Comment: Martin as you pointed the data read from sqlite is not the same as data written to it. Am i missing anything while reading blob data from sqlite? Thanks for pointing this.

Comment: I do not see an obvious error. Perhaps the problem is in the writing part? Is the data completely different or only some bytes? Is the length correct? Can you check the contents of the database with the sqlite3 command line tool and compare?

Comment: After using sqlite3_bind_blob API for inserting data i am getting the error as edited in the above question

Comment: If you show your inserting code we can try to find the problem. Without the code it is difficult to guess :-)

Comment: Martin Thanks for reply, i have edited the code for Archive & Unarchive above.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the code how to insert the data into sqlite.

Comment: Martin Thanks for reply and sorry for adding my comment late :(. I could solve the issue by converting NSData to bytes while adding it to SQL e.g., [nsdata bytes].

Comment: Keyedarchiver results in non human readable stuff, which can break in the future, if for instance some of the objects inside the dictionary change, and you don't do backwards support. If on the other hand you create JSON strings from the dictionary, they are future proof, and can be sent on the wire to web servers, etc. This only works if your dictionary is made of strings, numbers arrays and other dictionaries only.

Answer (score 0):

```
// To read data do following
-(void) readAnimalsFromDatabase {

    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Init the animals Array
    dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &amp;database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from anyTable";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &amp;compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Read the data from the result row
                NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                NSString *aImageUrl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

                NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:aName, @"name", aDescription, @"description", aImageUrl, @"imageURL", nil];

                // Add the animal object to the animals Array
                [dataArray addObject:dict];

            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);


    // Archive NSArray to NSData
    NSData *archiveData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dataArray];

    // UnArchive NSData to NSDictionary
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]];
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
}
```

Comment: As Martin pointed out the data read and written into sqlite is different that might be cause of the issue. I am still getting the same error even after using the above mentioned method.

Comment: Dipen, i am getting the error as edited in the above question. Could you provide me any pointers for the same.